# Add a label to specific posts, for example when 'sold' or 'now available' etc

Tags: wordpress, post, label, banner

hoped for a simple solution but didn't find one so far.. What I would like is to have the option to click a checkbox (or add category, tag etc.) for a specific post so it would show a banner/label over the featured image, like a .png image or peace of html (span for example).

This is for the possibility to give posts some extra attention, kind of similar actually as the Woocommerce feature 'sold' or 'out of stock'.

Any suggestions for plugins, peaces of script etc.? Like I said, couldn't find anything..

Hope to hear from you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry.. Found it! https://wordpress.org/plugins/templatic-badge/ It's enough to work with, some css styling, add background images etc. ;)

Comment: You could easily do this using a special category, too, and checking for it with `is_category()` in your (child) theme/template part files. If you ever wanted to do it without a plug-in, that is.